# como enviar un post y una imagen a la base de datos

Tags: php, pdo

Hola quiero subir una imagen y un comentario a mi base de datos este es mi form
ahora el problema es

como hago que ambos formularios compartan los mismos datos
asi cuando se publican en la base de datos se publique el comentario y la imagen

```
//form en el index
<form class="" action="post.php" method="post">
            <div class="input-group flex-nowrap">
              <div class="input-group-prepend" style="display:none;">
                <span class="input-group-text" id="addon-wrapping"></span>
              </div>
              <input type="text" maxlength="280" name="input-post" class="form-control" placeholder="¿Que estas pensando?" aria-describedby="addon-wrapping">
            </div>
            <br>
            <button type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-outline-primary">Compartir</button>

          </form>
          <form>
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="exampleFormControlFile1"><i class="far fa-image"></i></label>
              <input type="file" class="form-control-file" id="exampleFormControlFile1">
            </div>
          </form>

//Archivo post.php
<?php
session_start();
$user = $_SESSION['user'];
$date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');//$_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST'
if (!isset($_POST['submit'])) {
  $post = isset($_POST['input-post']) ? $_POST['input-post'] : "null";
  $conexion = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=web',"root","");
  //$conexion->set_charset('utf8mb4');
  $conexion->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
  $statement = $conexion->prepare("INSERT INTO post(usuario, cuerpo,time_date_post) VALUES (:username,:post,:time_date_post)");

  $statement->bindParam(':username', $user);
  $statement->bindParam(':post', $post);
  $statement->bindParam(':time_date_post', $date);
  $statement->execute();
}
header("Location: /");
 ?>
```

esta es mi tabla en la base de datos
CREATE TABLE `post` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `usuario` varchar(250) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_bin NOT NULL,
  `cuerpo` mediumtext CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_bin NOT NULL,
  `img` varchar(2500) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_bin DEFAULT NULL,
  `time_date_post` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci ROW_FORMAT=COMPACT;

Answer (score 2):

Hola respondiendo a tu pregunta, normalmente las imágenes yo las guardo en un directorio por lo que traté de acomodar tu código brindando ambas opciones: 1 guardando la imagen como fichero en un directorio, 2 guardarlo en base64 en la base de datos.

A parte reajuste un poco el HTML utilizando un solo formulario para que haga una sola petición. También debes estar atento de usar el atributo `enctype="multipart/form-data"` en el formulario cuando quieras usar input del tipo file.

HTML Modificado:

```
<!-- form -->
<form class="" action="post.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">

    <!-- input comment -->
    <div class="input-group flex-nowrap">
        <div class="input-group-prepend" style="display:none;">
            <span class="input-group-text" id="addon-wrapping"></span>
        </div>
        <input type="text" maxlength="280" name="input-post" class="form-control" placeholder="¿Que estas pensando?" aria-describedby="addon-wrapping">
    </div>
    <br>

    <!-- input file -->
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="exampleFormControlFile1"><i class="far fa-image"></i></label>
        <input type="file" name="image" class="form-control-file" id="exampleFormControlFile1">
    </div>

    <!-- button submit -->
    <button type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-outline-primary">Compartir</button>
</form>
```

Opción #1 para post.php (guardando imagen en un directorio)

```
<!-- file: post.php -->
<?php
    session_start();

    if(isset($_POST["submit"])) {

        // vars init after POST
        $user = $_SESSION['user'];
        $date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');

        $post = isset($_POST['input-post']) ? $_POST['input-post'] : "null";
        $conexion = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=web',"root","");

        $conexion->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        $statement = $conexion->prepare("INSERT INTO post(usuario, cuerpo,time_date_post) VALUES (:username,:post,:time_date_post)");
        $statement->bindParam(':username', $user);
        $statement->bindParam(':post', $post);
        $statement->bindParam(':time_date_post', $date);
        $result = $statement->execute();

        /*
         * habría que validar este código pero yo verificaría luego que se registre el comentario
         * guardar la imagen en algún directorio
         * */
        if($statement)
        {
            $path_dir = "./uploads/";
            $path_file = $path_dir . basename($_FILES["image"]["name"]);
            $uploadOk = 1;
            $imageFileType = strtolower(pathinfo($path_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION));

            $check = getimagesize($_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"]);
            if($check !== false) {
                $uploadOk = 1;
            } else {
                $uploadOk = 0;
            }
        }
    }

    // redirection
    header("Location: /");
?>
```

Opción #2 para post.php (guardando imagen en base de datos codificada como base64)

```
<!-- file: post.php -->
<?php
    session_start();

    if(isset($_POST["submit"])) {

        // vars init after POST
        $user = $_SESSION['user'];
        $date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');

        $post = isset($_POST['input-post']) ? $_POST['input-post'] : "null";
        $conexion = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=web',"root","");

        // encode base64 image
        $image = file_get_contents($_FILES['image']);
        $imageBase64 = base64_encode($image);

        $conexion->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        $statement = $conexion->prepare("INSERT INTO post(usuario, cuerpo, img, time_date_post) VALUES (:username,:post,:imageBase64,:time_date_post)");
        $statement->bindParam(':username', $user);
        $statement->bindParam(':post', $post);
        $statement->bindParam(':imageBase64', $imageBase64);
        $statement->bindParam(':time_date_post', $date);
        $result = $statement->execute();
    }

    // redirection
    header("Location: /");
?>
```

Tal ves tenga algún fallo de tipografía porque no lo probé pero espero te sirva para hacerte una idea clara de como hacerlo.

Comment: Nop no me funciono ninguna de las dos opciones pero muchas gracias

Answer (score 1):

Espero que estés bien, primero debes saber que el tipo usado para imágenes en Bases de datos es `LONGBLOB` a menos que solo quieras almacenar su nombre o dirección, no se si entendí mal lo que escribiste pero según entendí tienes el `form` de la imagen y el de los comentarios en tablas distintas, de ser así tienes asociar las tablas por medio de una llave foránea principalmente, pero si entendí mal lo pues ellas al estar en la misma tabla se van a mostrar juntas según como las tengas posicionadas en el formulario ah y veo que no has especificado a ID como `primary key` y al ser una publicación podrías ponerle NULL AUTO_INCREMENT para que su id incremente automáticamente.
Espero haberte ayudado de lo contrario estaré al tanto para aprender también :D.

Comment: pues no todo esta en una sola tabla, y lo que quiero es guardar el archivo en el servidor y el nombre en la BD y que al publicar el comentario (del usuario) salga la imagen en tal caso si se publico